# Zoom Functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html, internet-explorer

I have a static background Image available on my Page. There is a toolbar from where i can drag and drop images on the static Background Image discussed above. Now i need the ability to zoom the background image but at the same time the images which were drag and dropped on the top of this background image should also zoom and accordingly move their positions to look like as if it is just a single image on which i am working. I need to get this work only for IE browser. I have tried the -ms-zoom but the images which were drag and dropped doesn't seem to change their position at all since they are absolute positioned. The Browser built in Zoom seem to work perfect but our client needs a custom link on the page to zoom in and zoom out since we need only a particular section of the page to zoom and not the complete page.

Is there any way i can accomplish this requirement?

Comment: share on jsfiddle.com and get answer and upvotes in few minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `zoom` should work as you described. Try this:

```
<script>
a=100;
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="div" style="position:absolute;z-index:-1;top:50px;left:0px;width:400px;
    height:400px;background:url(some_image.jpg)"
>
    <img src="another_image.png" style="position:absolute; top:50px;left:50px;" />
</div>
<button onclick="a+=50;document.getElementById('div').style.zoom=a+'%';">
Zoom
</button>
```

Comment: Thanksssss a lot!!! It worked perfect. Howewer on IE8 it's behaving differently. Might be a bug with IE8?

Comment: @user984369 I couldn't reproduce any different behavior in IE8, though I can only emulate IE8 in IE9. The code above seems to work fine in every browsermode in IE9. Also I've used `zoom` in a real IE8 in the past, and there was no problems. Maybe it's something else in your code?

Comment: Well in some IE8 browsers it seem to work and in some doesn't. Anywas the code was really helpful provided by you. Thanks a lot.